# Pointer being freed was not allocated with STL vector (OS X only)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, memory-management

I am bumping into a couple of issues for which I can't really pinpoint the root cause, but they all have to do with managing memory when using multithreading. One of the persistent bugs that I am facing sometimes, as in I am not able to consistently reproduce it, is the following.

The program is running fine under Ubuntu 16, but is causing issues on OS X High Sierra, throwing malloc_error_break errors. Without multithreading everything *seems* to run fine, no complaints from valgrind or breakpoints being hit. The program needs to generate a sequence of numbers with a specific schedule, determined by the characteristics of the parent object (in the base_values class).

What happens in terms of multithreading is the following: We have a vector of objects for which experiments needs to be run using Monte Carlo simulation. After the simulation is done, a couple of transformations needs to be done on the generated data. As some key components to the vector of objects is unknown at compile time, one single Monte Carlo trial is evaluated in a single threaded environment to prevent race conditions over here. It is just a quick fix, a better solution will be implemented. The initialised vectors are stored and the remaining Monte Carlo trials will be evaluated in a multithreading environment (currently hardcoded to 4 threads).

The multithreading part of the code is as follows:

```
std::vector< std::vector<double> > evaluated_results(experiments.size(), std::vector<double>(mc_sim.getTrials(), 0.0));
std::vector<experiment*>::iterator experiment_iterator;
for (experiment_iterator = batched_experiments.begin(); experiment_iterator != (batched_experiments.end()); ++experiment_iterator){
    std::vector<double> monte_carlo_outcomes;
    monte_carlo_outcomes = experiment_iterator[0]->getMCValues();
    if (experiment_values.size() != 0) {
        evaluated_results[experiment_iterator - batched_experiments.begin()][0] = evaluateResult(experiment_iterator[0], monte_carlo_outcomes[0]);
        std::vector<double>::iterator mc_iterator;
        for (mc_iterator = monte_carlo_outcomes.begin() + 1; (mc_iterator + 4) < monte_carlo_outcomes.end(); mc_iterator += 4) {
            std::promise<float> value_1;
            std::promise<float> value_2;
            std::promise<float> value_3;
            std::promise<float> value_4;
            auto fut_1 = std::async(std::launch::async, evaluateTrial, experiment_iterator[0], mc_iterator[0]);
            auto fut_2 = std::async(std::launch::async, evaluateTrial, experiment_iterator[0], mc_iterator[1]);
            auto fut_3 = std::async(std::launch::async, evaluateTrial, experiment_iterator[0], mc_iterator[2]);
            auto fut_4 = std::async(std::launch::async, evaluateTrial, experiment_iterator[0], mc_iterator[3]);
            evaluated_results[experiment_iterator - batched_experiments.begin()][mc_iterator - monte_carlo_outcomes.begin()] = fut_1.get();
            evaluated_results[experiment_iterator - batched_experiments.begin()][(mc_iterator + 1) - monte_carlo_outcomes.begin()] = fut_2.get();
            evaluated_results[experiment_iterator - batched_experiments.begin()][(mc_iterator + 2) - monte_carlo_outcomes.begin()] = fut_3.get();
            evaluated_results[experiment_iterator - batched_experiments.begin()][(mc_iterator + 3) - monte_carlo_outcomes.begin()] = fut_4.get();
        }

        // Clean up residuals
        for (; mc_iterator != monte_carlo_outcomes.end(); ++mc_iterator) {
            evaluated_results[experiment_iterator - batched_experiments.begin()][mc_iterator - monte_carlo_outcomes.begin()] = evaluateTrial(experiment_iterator[0], mc_iterator[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Using LLDB's backtrace leads to the following analysis. Most of the code seems fine to me, up to the point where this->_begin in the deallocate call in vector:931 starts to contain bogus values. I've no idea what is going on, help would be greatly appreciated.

The problem seems to start off in this part, where values_ is an std::vector of type double:

```
void base_values::calculateNumberSequence() {
    if (values_.size() == 0) {
        calculateNumberOfRequiredValues();
    }
    switch (sequence_type_) {
        case Uniform:
            redemption_profile_ = calculateUniformSequence(values_.size());
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

std::vector<double> base_values::calculateUniformSequence(const int num_values) {
    std::vector<double> number_sequence_(num_values, seed_);
    return redemption_profile;
}
```

Frame analysis shows the following:
**Frame **
Vector 1303:

```
template <class _Tp, class _Allocator>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
vector<_Tp, _Allocator>&
vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::operator=(vector&& __x)
NOEXCEPT((__noexcept_move_assign_container<_Allocator, __alloc_traits>::value))
{
--> __move_assign(__x, integral_constant<bool,
__alloc_traits::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value>());
return *this;
}

_x contains 1 value, same as redemption_profile
_begin  std::__1::__vector_base<double, std::__1::allocator >::pointer  0x144935190 0x0000000144935190
_end    std::__1::__vector_base<double, std::__1::allocator >::pointer  0x144935378 0x0000000144935378
_end_cap    std::__1::__compressed_pair<double *, std::__1::allocator >
```

1327 in vector

```
template <class _Tp, class _Allocator>
void
vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::__move_assign(vector& __c, true_type)
NOEXCEPT(is_nothrow_move_assignable<allocator_type>::value)
{
--> deallocate();
__base::__move_assign_alloc(__c); // this can throw
this->_begin = __c._begin;
this->_end = __c._end;
this->__end_cap() = __c.__end_cap();
__c._begin = __c._end = __c.__end_cap() = nullptr;
#if _LIBCPP_DEBUG_LEVEL >= 2
__get_db()->swap(this, &__c);
#endif
}
```

931 in vector:

```
template <class _Tp, class _Allocator>
void
vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::deallocate() _NOEXCEPT
{
if (this->_begin != nullptr)
{
clear();
--> __alloc_traits::deallocate(this->__alloc(), this->_begin, capacity());
this->_begin = this->_end = this->__end_cap() = nullptr;
}
}

this: this  std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator > *    0x000000010064fbd0 size=1 0x000000010064fbd0
std::__1::__vector_base<double, std::__1::allocator >   std::__1::__vector_base<double, std::__1::allocator >
_begin  std::__1::__vector_base<double, std::__1::allocator >::pointer  0x14273b7c0 0x000000014273b7c0
_end    std::__1::__vector_base<double, std::__1::allocator >::pointer  0x14273b9a8 0x000000014273b9a8
_end_cap    std::__1::__compressed_pair<double *, std::__1::allocator >
```

memory 1510:

```
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
static void deallocate(allocator_type& __a, pointer __p, size_type __n) _NOEXCEPT
--> {__a.deallocate(__p, __n);}

__a allocator_type &    0x000000010064fbe0
__n size_type   61
__p pointer 0x14053e7a0 0x000000014053e7a0
*__p    double  0
```

memory 1750:

```
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY void deallocate(pointer __p, size_type) _NOEXCEPT
--> {_VSTD::__libcpp_deallocate((void*)__p);}

this    std::__1::allocator *   0x10064fbe0 0x000000010064fbe0
__p pointer 0x14053e7a0 0x000000014053e7a0
*__p    double  0
```

new 234:

```
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY void __libcpp_deallocate(void *__ptr) {
#ifdef _LIBCPP_HAS_NO_BUILTIN_OPERATOR_NEW_DELETE
::operator delete(__ptr);
#else
--> __builtin_operator_delete(__ptr);
#endif
}

__ptr   void *  0x14053e7a0 0x000000014053e7a0
```

LLDB shows the following output with -fsanitizer=threads, where main.cpp:182 refers to auto fut_3 = std::async(std::launch::async, evaluateTrial, experiment_iterator[0], mc_iterator[2]);

```
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=6469)
  Read of size 4 at 0x7b2c00000fa8 by main thread:
    #0 std::__1::future<float>::future(std::__1::__assoc_state<float>*) future:565 (ParticleGenerator:x86_64+0x10002a551)
    #1 std::__1::future<float>::future(std::__1::__assoc_state<float>*) future:1156 (ParticleGenerator:x86_64+0x100028098)
    #2 std::__1::future<float> std::__1::__make_async_assoc_state<float, std::__1::__async_func<float (*)(experiment*, double), experiment*, double> >(std::__1::__async_func<float (*)(experiment*, double), experiment*, double>&&) future:2302 (ParticleGenerator:x86_64+0x100027735)
    #3 std::__1::future<std::__1::__invoke_of<std::__1::decay<float (&)(experiment*, double)>::type, std::__1::decay<experiment*&, double&>::type>::type> std::__1::async<float (&)(experiment*, double), experiment*&, double&>(std::__1::launch, float (&&&)(experiment*, double), experiment*&&&, double&&&) future:2349 (ParticleGenerator:x86_64+0x10000cc3f)
    #4 main main.cpp:182 (ParticleGenerator:x86_64+0x100005ca3)

  Previous write of size 4 at 0x7b2c00000fa8 by thread T18 (mutexes: write M2138):
    #0 void std::__1::__assoc_state<float>::set_value<float>(float&&) future:670 (ParticleGenerator:x86_64+0x100028841)
    #1 std::__1::__async_assoc_state<float, std::__1::__async_func<float (*)(experiment*, double), experiment*, double> >::__execute() future:985 (ParticleGenerator:x86_64+0x100028224)
    #2 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (std::__1::__async_assoc_state<float, std::__1::__async_func<float (*)(experiment*, double), experiment*, double> >::*)(), std::__1::__async_assoc_state<float, std::__1::__async_func<float (*)(experiment*, double), experiment*, double> >*> >(void*) type_traits:4264 (ParticleGenerator:x86_64+0x100029ee8)

  Location is heap block of size 168 at 0x7b2c00000f20 allocated by main thread:
    #0 operator new(unsigned long) <null> (libclang_rt.tsan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x6a983)
    #1 std::__1::future<float> std::__1::__make_async_assoc_state<float, std::__1::__async_func<float (*)(experiment*, double), experiment*, double> >(std::__1::__async_func<float (*)(experiment*, double), experiment*, double>&&) future:2300 (ParticleGenerator:x86_64+0x1000273d8)
    #2 std::__1::future<std::__1::__invoke_of<std::__1::decay<float (&)(experiment*, double)>::type, std::__1::decay<experiment*&, double&>::type>::type> std::__1::async<float (&)(experiment*, double), experiment*&, double&>(std::__1::launch, float (&&&)(experiment*, double), experiment*&&&, double&&&) future:2349 (ParticleGenerator:x86_64+0x10000cc3f)
    #3 main main.cpp:182 (ParticleGenerator:x86_64+0x100005ca3)

  Mutex M2138 (0x7b2c00000f38) created at:
    #0 pthread_mutex_lock <null> (libclang_rt.tsan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x37aae)
    #1 std::__1::mutex::lock() <null> (libc++.1.dylib:x86_64+0x39c7e)
    #2 std::__1::__async_assoc_state<float, std::__1::__async_func<float (*)(experiment*, double), experiment*, double> >::__execute() future:985 (ParticleGenerator:x86_64+0x100028224)
    #3 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (std::__1::__async_assoc_state<float, std::__1::__async_func<float (*)(experiment*, double), experiment*, double> >::*)(), std::__1::__async_assoc_state<float, std::__1::__async_func<float (*)(experiment*, double), experiment*, double> >*> >(void*) type_traits:4264 (ParticleGenerator:x86_64+0x100029ee8)

  Thread T18 (tid=112849590, finished) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create <null> (libclang_rt.tsan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x283ed)
    #1 std::__1::thread::thread<void (std::__1::__async_assoc_state<float, std::__1::__async_func<float (*)(experiment*, double), experiment*, double> >::*)(), std::__1::__async_assoc_state<float, std::__1::__async_func<float (*)(experiment*, double), experiment*, double> >*, void>(void (std::__1::__async_assoc_state<float, std::__1::__async_func<float (*)(experiment*, double), experiment*, double> >::*&&)(), std::__1::__async_assoc_state<float, std::__1::__async_func<float (*)(experiment*, double), experiment*, double> >*&&) __threading_support:327 (ParticleGenerator:x86_64+0x100029440)
    #2 std::__1::thread::thread<void (std::__1::__async_assoc_state<float, std::__1::__async_func<float (*)(experiment*, double), experiment*, double> >::*)(), std::__1::__async_assoc_state<float, std::__1::__async_func<float (*)(experiment*, double), experiment*, double> >*, void>(void (std::__1::__async_assoc_state<float, std::__1::__async_func<float (*)(experiment*, double), experiment*, double> >::*&&)(), std::__1::__async_assoc_state<float, std::__1::__async_func<float (*)(experiment*, double), experiment*, double> >*&&) thread:360 (ParticleGenerator:x86_64+0x100028038)
    #3 std::__1::future<float> std::__1::__make_async_assoc_state<float, std::__1::__async_func<float (*)(experiment*, double), experiment*, double> >(std::__1::__async_func<float (*)(experiment*, double), experiment*, double>&&) future:2301 (ParticleGenerator:x86_64+0x1000276d2)
    #4 std::__1::future<std::__1::__invoke_of<std::__1::decay<float (&)(experiment*, double)>::type, std::__1::decay<experiment*&, double&>::type>::type> std::__1::async<float (&)(experiment*, double), experiment*&, double&>(std::__1::launch, float (&&&)(experiment*, double), experiment*&&&, double&&&) future:2349 (ParticleGenerator:x86_64+0x10000cc3f)
    #5 main main.cpp:182 (ParticleGenerator:x86_64+0x100005ca3)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race future:565 in std::__1::future<float>::future(std::__1::__assoc_state<float>*)
```

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Does the function `calculateNumberSequence` run in parallel?

Comment: You say that this code is using multithreading, however I don't see any synchronization here.

Comment: At the moment I can't provide a minimal example, I am working in that. In terms of multithreading, good point, forgot to mention that so I'll also edit the post. What is happening is that a first run is done for every single hypothesis or object in a vector to initialise a couple of important vectors. One of them is this one. These feed into a Monte Carlo simulation part that runs in parallel. Hopefully that clarifies it.

Comment: The code after _"The multithreading part of the code is as follows:"_ doesn't seem useful, or related to the rest of the question (it doesn't use `base_values` or the function that you say appears in the stack trace; it has four completely unused `promise` objects).

Comment: Have you tried using `-fsanitize=thread` or `-fsanitize=address` ?

Comment: -fsanitize=thread is actually showing data races on the auto fut_3 = std::async(std::launch::async, evaluateTrial, experiment_iterator[0], mc_iterator[2]); line! Now only need to understand why. Error says: Location is heap block of size 168 at 0x7b2c00000f20 allocated by main thread, but the memory browser shows bogus values for that location. evaluateTrial initialises a struct with trial specific settings. Could this be the case? I am fighting myself through the output ATM. Will edit the original post with the output.